# Is React Hooks useState async?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help.

I expected that when I click the button(red circle), the showPopUp in handleClick runs, and here the "popup" should be true, but it wasn't.
I thought, the showPopUp(setState) is async and the console.log run first.

What's the actual matter was and How can I use the useState function synchronously like Promise function?

Comment: State updates are indeed asynchronous

Comment: `useState` Hook is synchronous. The returned state updater function is synchronous. React state updates are asynchronously processed.